# How to assign parameter values for sp_executesql directly from table?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have this piece of code:

```
DECLARE @var1 int
DECLARE @var1Value int = 10

DECLARE @sSQL nvarchar(max) = N'SELECT @var1 = @var1Value';
DECLARE @ParmDefinition nvarchar(max) = N'@var1 int OUTPUT, @var1Value int';

DECLARE @ParmValues varchar(max) = (select paramsValues from Table_1 where id = 1)

EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT @var1 = @var1Value', N'@var1 int OUTPUT,  
                   @var1Value int',  @ParmValues
```

@ParmValues is equals to `'@var1Value = @var1Value,@var1= @var1 OUTPUT'`.

This code throws an error of conversion from int to varchar, but if a run the assignments directly, with no query from the table, it works ok.

```
EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT @var1 = @var1Value', N'@var1 int OUTPUT,  
@var1Value int',  @var1Value = @var1Value,@var1= @var1 OUTPUT
```

Is there a way to take the assignments directly from the table?

Thank you for the answers.

Comment: what is the error you are getting?? what are the values in (select paramsValues from Table_1 where id = 1)

Comment: How is it supposed to work? Unknown number of values, undeclared variables...

Comment: Don’t think there is a way to do that. I think the best way is to use a cursor an execute in a loop

Comment: Have you tried declaring `@ParmValues` as `nvarchar`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use dynamic SQL.  Build up the a string from its component parts, and then execute that.

Note: The string is executed in its own scope, so any variables referenced must appear in the string itself.

```
create table Table_1 ( ID int, paramsValues varchar(max) )

insert into Table_1 ( ID, paramsValues ) values
( 1, '@var1Value = @var1Value,@var1= @var1 OUTPUT' )

DECLARE @sSQL nvarchar(max) = N'SELECT @var1 = @var1Value';
DECLARE @ParmDefinition nvarchar(max) = N'@var1 int OUTPUT, @var1Value int';

DECLARE @ParmValues varchar(max) = (select paramsValues from Table_1 where id = 1)

declare @S nvarchar(300)

set @S =  'DECLARE @var1 int '
        + 'DECLARE @var1Value int = 10 '
        + 'EXEC sp_executesql '
        + 'N''' + @sSQL + ''','
        + 'N''' + @ParmDefinition + ''','
        + @ParmValues

exec sp_executesql @S
```

Comment: And how to make the variables visible not only in its own scope?

Comment: You can't.  The code run from within sp_executesql runs as if it has its own session.  So you cannot communicate between sessions with variables.  But there are other options, such as setting up a temporary table.  If you can give me a better idea of what you're trying to achieve maybe I can give you better guidance.

Comment: This sounds a lot like an XY Problem.  I'm having trouble imagining how putting parameter names and values into a string stored in a table is the best way to solve a problem.  If you can explain what you're trying to achieve maybe we can give you a better solution.

Comment: I'm refactoring some nested SP and I want to put the most code I can into some table.

Comment: Maybe you could create a new question with an example of how putting code into a table would help you.  Then perhaps we could come up with a solution to the problem you are trying to solve.